# SQL order by datetime formatted as dd.MM.yyyy is incorrect

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-order-by

I have problems sorting my data in the correct order.
I have tried a few different combinations but they all return the data in the wrong manner.
The date column is in `datetime` format.
A few codes that i have tried:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), recievedDate, 104) as day
FROM table
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), recievedDate, 104)
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), recievedDate, 104)
```

Returns data as:

```
01.02.2021
01.03.2021
01.04.2021
02.02.2021
02.03.2021
...
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), recievedDate, 121)),'dd.MM.yyyy')
FROM table
GROUP BY FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), recievedDate, 121)),'dd.MM.yyyy')
ORDER BY FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), recievedDate, 121)),'dd.MM.yyyy')
```

Which returns same results.

But what i want is:

```
01.01.2021
02.01.2021
03.01.2021
01.02.2021
```

And so on. I really don't know why it groups up all the months then orders them by the day.

Comment: If `[date]` (you should really rename that) is a `date`/`datetime` datatype, why don't you just sort by it? `ORDER BY [date]`

Comment: i recive it in MM-dd-yyyy  HH:mm:ssss datetime format so i convert it

Comment: `datetime` has no format, what you see on the screen is a representation based on your local settings. Anyway, if you want to sort a date, make sure it is the correct datatype.

Comment: yes but i am working with API so i need it to work the way it is set ....not my own local settings

Comment: Additionally, `FORMAT` is a performance killer

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no set functions are involved? Are you just trying to do SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: There is more data to the query but i removed it since i only needed this specific fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the `datetime` by converting to `date` and format the date *after* grouping:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(date, recievedDate), 104)
FROM t
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, recievedDate)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date, recievedDate)
```

Comment: i renamed the column for convinience...but this code returns :       `Column 'recievedDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: You definitely made a typo or changed the expression in select part. I am using `CONVERT(date, recievedDate)` in group by, then formatting the exact same expression.

Comment: Oh my yes i did , my bad..... It works now thank you for your help :D

Comment: What exactly are you using the group by for? In your code it looks like you want to combine all records for a particular date e.g. `2021-12-02 01:00` and `2021-12-02 23:00` into one.

Comment: well yes i have lots more data but i do not want to show them / 2 much code to rename. But as i said you already solved my issues thank you :)